# string calculation with an exponent

Tags: java, calculator

I am making a calculator and I am trying to figure out how to convert an equation's exponent when it is already in a string. for example, if the user enters

2 + 3 * (4/2) + 6.23^4.2 + 32

as a string how would i calculated the 6.23^4.2 along with the rest of the equation.

I can already calculate an equation without an exponent, just having issues with the exponent part. Using a GUI

Edit: I know math.pow, but how would i extract the 6.23 and 4.2 from the string, calculate their exponent, and reinsert it back into the string?

This is how I am currently calculating the equation without an exponent:

```
            ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
            ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
            String infix = textField.getText();
            if (countR != countL || op == false) {
                textField.setText("ERROR");

            } else {
                try {
                    Object obj = engine.eval(infix);
                    textField.setText(obj.toString());
                } catch (ScriptException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    textField.setText("ERROR");
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
```

Comment: Try `Math.pow(6.23, 4.2)`

Comment: I know math.pow, but how would i extract the 6.23 and 4.2 from the string, calculate their exponent, and reinsert it back into the string to be calculated as a complete equation?

Comment: Then you should provide what you have attempted. In your question, you stated that you have no issues without an exponent.

Comment: @ShanSolo How are you extracting the other ones? Similarly.

Comment: Is this a homework?

Comment: Kind of. My homework was to create a simple calculator, but I am trying to add in exponents, parenthesis, decimals, etc. for my own interest

Comment: I'm thinking if your homework can make use of `ScriptEngine.eval()`, since IMO your class want to teach you about String operation and looping

Comment: Here the operator `^` is `XOR` boolean operation which is why your output might come wrong. Thus you have to parse the String and replace the `(6.23^4.2)` portion with `Math.pow(6.23, 4.2)` in the final String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the two `double` numbers`(6.23^4.2)` and use `Math.pow(6.23, 4.2)` to calculate.

***EDIT***

Here the operator `^`is `XOR` boolean operation which is why your output might come wrong. Thus you have to parse the `String` and replace the `(6.23^4.2)` portion with `Math.pow(6.23, 4.2)` in the final `String`

Comment: added additional info

Comment: How are you extracting the other ones? Similarly.

Comment: @ShanSolo Updated the answer.

Comment: seems like this would work, gonna try it out. thank you!